# One Logstash to Multiple Elasticsearch Indexes with CertainFields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I intend to have one logstash to parse 5 fields and send only certain fields to certain indexes.

Example
Field 01
Field 02
Field 03
Field 04
Field 05

index-a
Field 01
Field 02
Field 03

index-b
Field 01
Field 04
Field 05

Can this be done with just one logstash script?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [the `clone` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-clone.html). This allows you to duplicate events and tag them differently, allowing different filter and output stages later on.

```
if [type] == 'cloneable' {
  clone {
    clones => [ 'squarefile', 'roundfile' ]
  }
}
```

For events that pass the conditional, they will be cloned into new events with the types `squarefile` and `roundfile`. Later `filter {}` and `output {}` blocks can affect them separately.